# Through what method is a Collection bound to the ItemsSource property

Tags: wpf, data-binding, itemssource

I've been binding a Collection to a ListView and now I'm curious about the way this happens for WPF.

The main question is **How WPF accesses the items of the collection?** *GetEnumerator* is never called when binding.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *my* WPF `GetEnumerator` is called. I do not know how you came to this conclusion but if you implement the interface and set breakpoints you can see as much. The binding system however also checks for `IList` and may access items via the `Count` & indexer, `GetEnumerator` seems to be called regardness though.

Comment: I have a breakpoint in GetEnumerator and this[] and no breakpoint is hit when all the items are displayed in the UI

Comment: @Arturo: What interfaces does your collection implement? Do you use the generic versions? Does a base class already implement the non-generic versions which may be used without you noticing?

Comment: Implements IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Found the problem. I was implementing IListSource and it was breaking INotifyCollectionChanged functionality.